# How to randomly generate a date and time that take place after another date and time

Tags: r, simulation

I want to generate random POSIX date and times that are after another randomly generated date and time to make a simulated dataset but I'm struggling with getting it right.

So far, I've learned several ways to NOT do it. For example, I've tried using a sample of a sequence within a date range for the first date and then tried to reference the first date as the beginning date range for the second generated date. However, a sequence can only have a length of one so I can't get this to work for more than one generated value.

```
x <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2010-01-01'), as.POSIXct('2019-01-01'), by="sec"), 1)
y <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct(x),            as.POSIXct('2017-01-01'), by="sec"), 1)
```

Comment: You can't 'just do' this. You need to specify a distribution that you think the simulated data should have. For example, you might think the lag times between an initial time and the subsequent time are exponential, then you can simulate the lags & add them to the original times.

Comment: I'm unclear exactly what the desired output is here. What distribution are you sampling from exactly? Rather than sampling two vectors of dates, try sampling one vector of dates, and then generate a random number of minutes/hours/days to add to that first date.

Comment: Sounds like you need to study the distribution of times between events.  Either assume a distribution based on theoretical grounds, or collect some data and fit a distribution to the inter-event times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are looking for the maximum of two random datetimes where each random datetime is uniformly distributed over a given datetime interval:

```
set.seed(123)

n <- 5  # no of random datetimes needed
minDate <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01")
maxDate <- as.POSIXct("2000-12-31")

epoch <- "1970-01-01"
as.POSIXct(pmax(runif(n, minDate, maxDate), runif(n, minDate, maxDate)), origin = epoch)
## [1] "2000-04-15 00:10:44 EDT" "2000-10-14 18:33:10 EDT"
## [3] "2000-11-21 17:35:26 EST" "2000-11-18 07:13:56 EST"
## [5] "2000-12-09 06:29:36 EST"
```